# Column wise validation and insert update column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Scenario: there is two different table and one is live data table and another is archive or history table. we want to identify the column which got updated by user and only those column should update into history table. [enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy73I.png

in image there is one variance column that only need to update in history table. if anyone having any idea about to write logic please help us. thank you...

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to provide more context. Post what you have tried and what the problem is. Provide Code. And maybe a little example. How can the user update the table? What information about the user input do you have?

Comment: Hi @sanjeev, please rephrase your problem and what you want to achieve. The only thing I can think of at this minute is that you may take advantage of the MERGE statement to update your history table: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html